# Capistrano 3.0 Rails 5.0.0 database custom task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

I have deployed a Rails app on an Ubuntu server with Capistrano. However I am trying to run a custom task I had created and is in 'lib/tasks'. I tried to make it work by executing

cap production db:views

As if it was a custom task, but obviously it did not worked

> cap aborted!
>   Don't know how to build task 'db:views'

The file is `sql_views.rake`, this task is for create views in the database

```
namespace :db do
  desc "Update and create SQL views"
  task :views => :environment do
    Dir["#{Rails.root}/db/sql_views/*.sql"].each do |file_name|
      STDERR.puts "Applying the SQL view at #{file_name}"
      source_file = File.new(file_name, 'r')

      if source_file and (sql_content = source_file.read)
        ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
          # Each statement ends with a semicolon followed by a newline.
          sql_lines = sql_content.split(/;[ \t]*$/)
          if sql_lines.respond_to?(:each)
            sql_lines.each do |line|
              ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "#{line};"
            end
          end
        end # transaction
      end

    end # Dir.each
  end # task
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you used `cap install` to generate your `Capfile`, the following lines should be present:

```
# Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks` if you have any defined
Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
```

So it's looking in `lib/capistrano/tasks` for custom tasks.

Move `lib/tasks/sql_views.rake` to `lib/capistrano/tasks/sql_views.rake`

Or just import each rake task:

```
import 'lib/tasks/sql_views.rake'
```